# How can I generate 1200 kV with a 15 kV 30 mA 60 hertz NST?

Tags: capacitor

On a voltage multiplier it stopped working because of too many stages. If I rectified it then used a Marx generator would that work instead? I don't know if a Marx generator will stop working after a certain amount of stages. I could generate the high voltage while using a Tesla coil as well, then rectifying it. All I’m trying to do is create a high voltage DC to charge a very very large capacitor made out of activated carbon.

Comment: Isn't 15 kV at 30 mA like 450 Watts? How are you insulating (or planning to insulate) against 1.2 MV? I don't have the first idea how to help you but I am curious about your project. Seems like it might have the potential to induce dielectric breakdown.

Comment: Please define your terms: what's an NST?

Comment: neon-sign transformer (NST)

Comment: You cannot even think about generating 1.2MV until you have mastered 500 kV.   Do you know the 3D E-field gradient stress at that potential? Have you mastered control of partial discharge? Don't even think of doing 500 kV until you have mastered 100 kV safely and reliably..

Comment: Think and compute the power to drive 1 Gohm leakage at 1GV or even 10 stage 100kV in a pristine clean environment then compare that with the power rating of an NST

Comment: I’ve been seeing people on YouTube using oil transformers or fly back transformers to power there 1000kv Marx generators. I think a neon sign transformer should would. The oil burner transformer I believe is 60 hertz but the fly back is like 30 kilohertz. The NST is 60hertz. Now idk I just wish one of you had an NST and tried it for yourselves for me. I’m too poor to keep doing experiments. I don’t have the equipment, sorry y’all. I would.

Comment: This is not 500kV, only using point sources with 1kV/mm with sharp wires, but if  it arced using spheres then it could be  3kV /mm in dry air or e.g. 30mm *3kV = 90 kV  Don't waste our time with pretenders but have fun https://youtu.be/dje7uhyW23o?t=455  UHV insulation is a science.  Also stretching arcs is low voltage due to negative resistance.  (-1 for lack of due dilgence)

Answer (score 2):

Beyond about 10:1 the multiplier method gives rapidly diminishing returns with reasonable assumptions. Read a paper on it maybe 25 years ago (Cockcroft-Walton type).

Neon sign transformers have relatively high leakage inductance by design so you can also expect the output voltage to drop quite a bit before you get close to the rated current.

If you don’t mind motors and belts there is always the Van de Graaff generator approach, however an air-insulated generator for 1.2MV would be relatively large, perhaps 3m (10 feet) tall. Compact high voltage equipment requires special techniques such as sulfur hexafluoride dielectric gas- nasty and a very bad greenhouse gas. Your transformer would be used as part of the spray DC power supply at the low potential end.

Comment: C-W multipliers yes are limited by branching of current and continuous leakage, but Marx Gens can have lower air gap leakage but need a reliable trigger to sync all arcs.  A motor-driven surface with leather friction is used for static gen ~ 50kV with high power then drives a Marx gen with an NST just for the trigger.